# Let $S =\{1,2,3,4,5 \} $ For each give a brief explanation and simply answer to a number. (a) How many functions $f: S \longrightarrow S$ are there?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

(b) How many one-to-one functions $f : S\longrightarrow S$ are there?

(c) How many functions $f : S \longrightarrow S$ are there so that $f o f(1) = 2$ ?

(d) How many onto functions $f: S\longrightarrow S$  are there so that $f o f(1) = 2$ ?

I've figured out part a and part b. For part (a) I just took $2^5$ and i got the answer, and for part (b) I just took factorial. 
I understand the definition of onto and one-to-one. I can't figure out part (c) and part (d). Any help, highly appreciated.

Comment: You obtained that there are 32 functions and 5!=120 ono-to-one functions. Isn't it strange? The second (b) is the correct answer.

Comment: Here is a course-correction on part (a). Number of functions equals (5 choices for f(1)) x (5 choices for f(2)) x (5 choices for f(3)) x (5 choices for f(4)) x (5 choices for f(5)) = 5^5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(c) $f(1) = 2$ is chosen.  So you're left with counting all the partial maps $f: (S - \{1\}) \to S$.  There are $5^4$ such maps ($5$ possible for mapping $2 \to \dots$, times $5$ possible for mapping $3\to \dots$, and so on..., so $5 \times 5\times \dots \times 5 = 5^4$.

(d) We have $f\circ f (1) = 2$.  So $f$ can map $1 \to $ any of $2,3,4,5$ (not 1, why?), as long as it also maps that output to $2$.  So choose out of $2,3,4,5$ and that's $4$ possible choices, call the choice $x$.  Then it also needs to map $x \to 2$.  Thus there are $4$ choices for mapping $1 \to x$, $1$ choice for mapping $x$, and you have $3$ more inputs left to map, with a choice of any element in $S$, so the answer should be $4 \times 1 \times 5^3$.

Don't quote me on that :P